# Can't get andengine onAreaTouched to work

Tags: android, sprite, andengine

I'm following [this](http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/flappychick/9/#26) tutorial to get started with AndEngine, but I can't seem to get the sprite buttons to work.

The play again button worked for a little bit but all of a sudden it just stopped working. At this point, I've isolated the play again code to just this:

```
        final Text playText = new Text(playX, playY, mResourceManager.mFont2, "Play again", new TextOptions(HorizontalAlign.CENTER), mVertexBufferObjectManager) {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                Log.d("Area", "touched");
                if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
                    clearChildScene();
                    mSceneManager.setScene(SceneManager.SceneType.SCENE_GAME);
                    mHudText.setVisible(true);
                }
                return false;
            }
        };

        registerTouchArea(playText);
        setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
        attachChild(playText);
```

I don't even have this code inside a CameraScene anymore, and I've put this code inside an empty scene. Just like with the CameraScene, the text appears, but the touch doesn't work. The log doesn't even appear.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have to write a lot of letters to post the answer but it's still short one:

Change to:

```
return true;
```